# Not able to send app to background using BackHandler when control is coming from Android Fragment

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using RN 0.72.4, I'd like to send to the background RN app using BackHandler.exitApp. Currently, Android app is invoking a RN component which is parsing some information and it is sending back the information to Android. However, once this is done I would like to send to the background the RN app.

This is the snippet:

App.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import HomeScreen from "./Screens/HomeScreen";
import { JsonProps, RootStackParamList } from "./types/AppInfo";
import ShowInformation from "./components/ShowInformation";

export default function App(props: JsonProps): React.JSX.Element {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
  
  return (
    <>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="ShowInformation ">
          <Stack.Screen
            name="ReactNative"
            component={HomeScreen}
            initialParams={{ appList: props }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="ShowInformation " component={ShowInformation } />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </>
  );
}
```

ShowInformation.tsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Alert,
  NativeModules,
  Text,
  View,
  BackHandler
} from "react-native";
import { payload } from "../types/AppInfo";
import {EncodedInformation} from "../Encoder"

const ShowInformation = () => {
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(true);
  const [jsonInfo, setJSONInfo] = useState("");
 
  const parseCode = (rawData: string) => {
    const payload: payload = {
      status: "",
      fields: {
        surname: "",
        givenName: "",
      }
    };
    setFlag(false);
    payload.status = payload.fields.givenName === "" ? "Error" : "Success";

    setJSONInfo(JSON.stringify(payload));
    !payload.fields.givenName
      ? Alert.alert("Warning", "Not valid information", [{
            text: "OK",
            onPress: () => {
              console.log("Want to exit the application");
              return BackHandler.exitApp();
            }
          }
        ])
      : Alert.alert("Success", "Valid information", [{
            text: "OK",
            onPress: () => {
              console.log("Want to exit the application");
              return BackHandler.exitApp();
            }
          }
        ]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    NativeModules.ActivityStarter.setPayload(jsonCustomerInfo);
    BackHandler.exitApp();
  }, [jsonInfo, flag]);

  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        {flag && (
          <Text>Information</Text>
        )}
      </View>
      <View>
        {flag && (
          <EncodedInformation
            onReadCode={(event: {
              nativeEvent: { codeStringValue: string };
            }) => {
              parseCode(event.nativeEvent.codeStringValue);
              setFlag(false);
            }}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default ShowInformation;
```

**Update**

I tried the approach to use `killProcess` in a Native Module and invoke it in RN:

```
@ReactMethod
public void exitApp() {
    Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
}
```

and then use it in RN:

```
Alert.alert("Warning", "Card is not a valid Driver License", [
  {
    text: "OK",
    onPress: () => {
      RNExitApp.exitApp()
    }
  }
])
```

The above approach is killing the application, but I am back to the first fragment of the Action, instead of the last Fragment. So this option is not a choice.

I explore navigation with dispatching popAction and goBack:

```
import { StackActions } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { payload, RootStackParamList } from "../types/AppInfo";
import { NativeStackScreenProps } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";

const popAction = StackActions.pop(1);

type PageProps = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, "Page">;

const ShowInformation = ({ navigation }: PageProps) => {
  Alert.alert("Warning", "Invalid Information", [
  {
    text: "OK",
    onPress: () => {
      // navigation.dispatch(popAction);
      navigation.goBack();
    }
  }
])
: Alert.alert("Success", "Valid Information", [
  {
    text: "OK",
    onPress: () => {
      // navigation.dispatch(popAction);
      navigation.goBack();
    }
  }
]);
};
```

However, I am getting this error for navigation.go_back and navigation.dispatch(popAction):

```
ERROR  The action 'GO_BACK' ( was not handled by any navigator.

Is there any screen to go back to?

This is a development-only warning and   won't be shown in production.


The action 'POP' with payload {"count":1} was not handled by any navigator.

Is there any screen to go back to?

This is a development-only warning and won't be shown in production.
```

**Update 2**

I have working the same very minimum logic in this [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@chompiras/697117?platform=android). However, the same code is not working on my RN app. The only difference is that the control to access RN application is given by Android app. How could affect this fact when exiting the app in RN (which currently I am not able)?

If a press manually the back button then the RN application leaves and returns to the last Fragment in Android.

This is the section in Android Fragment that triggers the execution of RN app:

```
private void scan(){
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MyFirstReactActivity.class );
    i.putExtra("activityName", String.valueOf(getActivity()));
    startActivity(i);
  }
```

I'd like to send to the background the application, so I am back to the last Fragment in Android under these two scenarios:

1. When the user clicks on OK in any of the Alert messages.
2. At the end of "useEffect", so I do not show any Alert and at the end of "useEffect" I send the application to the background.

Can be this possible? What I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your kind response :)